# How do I stop the coroutine until one or more of multiple conditions are met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a Coroutine to stop until one of the conditions is met. Particularly, I need coroutine to wait until user presses one of two keys (R or T), or when my "timer" goes off, and then I need coroutine to continue. Timer is a float variable which I decrease by Time.deltaTime in Update method. Basically, I need to put a couple of conditions in yield return new WaitUntil() , if it is possible. I know how to write conditions themselves, but I don't know what to use to stop the coroutine until one of multiple conditions are met.

So is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: depends on which input system you use too

Comment: I use Input.GetKey()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
IEnumerator ConditionCoroutine()
{
    print("Before condition");
    
    yield return new WaitUntil(() =>
        (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) || IsTimerEnd)
    );
    
    print("After condition");
}
```

Comment: I meant I need to stop a script until one of the conditions is met, not stop it after the condition is met. Probably Mushroomator suggested the thing I need, I'll check it out now.

Comment: You mean: `yield return new WaitUntil(callback);` ?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. I need something like this, but I need to add multiple conditions to it and continue the coroutine when at least one of them are met

Comment: This would be a better option than the previous answer. In the previous answer, the conditions will be checked until the end of the game session, even when they are not needed, and here it is when the coroutine is called

Comment: @Kyzlyk that why it was an exmple of how to test for multiple things not a line by line code example.. but if I had just posted one line everyone would have moaned it had no context

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
IEnumerator ConditionCoroutine()
{
    print("Before condition");
    
    var hasPressedR = false;
    var hasPressedT = false;
    float timer = XY;
 
    while(true)
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) hasPressedR = true;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)) hasPressedT = true;

        if(timer <= 0 && hasPressedR && hasPressedT)
        {
            break;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
    
    print("After condition");
}
```

and avoid having a lot of fields in your class itself or depending on `Update`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are over complicating it.. so. This is not a whato todo but a working example of how to use multiple conditions.

I have not compiled this code so typos galor I expect..

```
bool inputreceived=false;
IEnumerator test()
{
   inputreceived = false;
   yield return new WaitUntil(inputreceived);
   dostuff();
}

void Start()
{
  StartCoroutine("test"); // or use a better non string manner
}

void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.R) || Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.T)) inputreceived=true;
}
```

Comment: @FixMixGames so why have you marked the above answer as right after saying it was wrong?